# Inserting hex value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, data-storage

I have created an SQL database using Java. I have a table created which has two columns, the first being a big integer which increments, the second I have tried defining it as a char, varchar and binary.

But I'm still not getting the desired functionality. Say I try and store a hex number `0a` into the char column and I get an error. I appended `0x` to the beginning and it seems to store, but when I print out the contents it is blank. Or in some cases I get characters such as '/' or '?'. I also tried using SQL explorer and it gives me the same result viewing the table,

My problem is I need to store an eight character *hex string* such as `eb8d4ee6`.

Could someone please advise me of how this can be done?

Answer (score 7):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

> MySQL supports hexadecimal values,
>   written using X'val', x'val', or 0xval
>   format, where val contains hexadecimal
>   digits (0..9, A..F). Lettercase of the
>   digits does not matter. For values
>   written using X'val' or x'val' format,
>   val must contain an even number of
>   digits. For values written using 0xval
>   syntax, values that contain an odd
>   number of digits are treated as having
>   an extra leading 0. For example, 0x0a
>   and 0xaaa are interpreted as 0x0a and
>   0x0aaa.
>
> In numeric contexts, hexadecimal
>   values act like integers (64-bit
>   precision). In string contexts, they
>   act like binary strings, where each
>   pair of hex digits is converted to a
>   character:

You probably should store the Hex number in an integer column. You can then convert back to hex when selecting using the [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function.

E.g.,

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (`MyIntegerColumn`) VALUES (0xeb8d4ee6);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply i have read this article, as i said im an sql noob, but i have tried to append 0x defining it as hex but when viewing the table the value is not there?

Comment: @user524156: Try defining the column as type `integer`.

Comment: this is my sql statment creating the table

Comment: String sql = "CREATE TABLE Table1(encrypt_key BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,encrypt_val VARCHAR(10),primary key (encrypt_key) )";

Comment: @user524156: see my example `INSERT`.

Comment: Ok integer wont work as the hex i need to store is 8 chars long, such as df0e8d7e, i used BIGINT and it stores but stores this as -552694402, this is not decimal for the hex number i inserted im not sure what it is, is there anyway just to the hex as is?, i will also need to search and match these values later if thats an issue when choosing how to save it.

Comment: Ok, I tested using BIGINT (`INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`MyBigIntColumn`) VALUES (0xDF0E8D7E);`). Selecting my inserted value back gave `3742272894`, and using the `HEX()` function on it returned `DF0E8D7E1`. Seems to work fine, not sure where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Json column:
And use `JSON.stringify(hex)` to insert and you can always get the result via select and compare too