# How to insert hex /binary ? into a mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql

i am trying to insert some hex values into a field of a mysql db

this is the kind of value i need to insert :

```
['D\x93\xb4s\xa5\x9eM\\\x14\xf3*\x95\xf9\x83\x1d*%P\xdb\xa2', 'D\xbf\xef\xb0\xc8\xff\x17\xc6Y6\xc6\xb4,p\xaa\xb1\xf2V\xdaa', 'D\xd7~~\x02\xd3|}\xfcN\xc1\x03\x97\x07\xb5<U\x16Y\x9e', '\xf3\xb6\xc2,Y/[i\x98\x93\x9d\xb2R\x93\x84\x12W\x1a3\x19', '\xf3\xb7\xce\x1f-n\x89\xb6\x87K\x9dsf\xcb=w\xab\x1a\xa0<', '\xf3\xbf7\x04d\xe6\xdf\xf8"9\x1d\x05\x01\xe4\xd4\xb0\xad\x80\xc0\xf5']
```

this is my table

```
 +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | consensus    | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | identityb32  | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | pubdate      | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | dirport      | char(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | ip           | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | orport       | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | identityhash | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | nick         | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | version      | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | flags        | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | identity     | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | digest       | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | pubtime      | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

currently i am adding the hex data as i would do a normal string but this results in a non readable input being added:

```
D??s??M?*???*%P?
```

how can the hex data be added?

Comment: [Search for UNHEX() and HEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). The usage is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks i have tried  (UNHEX(HEX(identity[c]))) but get the error NameError: name 'UNHEX' is not defined

Comment: I don't think it is either latin1 or utf8.  Perhaps it is binary or some other BLOB type of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

**Check CHARSET**

```
   CREATE TABLE `t` (
      `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way really is [HEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) and [UNHEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) functions. But, this post maybe help [Inserting hex value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306219/inserting-hex-value-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't hex values.

I may be way off on this, but the only way I found to insert your values, was like this:

```
$string = 'D\x93\xb4s\xa5\x9eM\\\x14\xf3*\x95\xf9\x83\x1d*%P\xdb\xa2';
$pattern = '#\\\#';
$replacement = '\\\\\\';
$insert_value = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

After which proceed to insert. You could use `VARCHAR(256)` for the column.

I'm positive there are a lot of better ways to go about this.

---

Apparently I'm on the python part of SO. I thought it was PHP. This is what I get for subscribing to multiple tags.

Comment: I think you are right about them not being hex values, are they binary string values instead ?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Deciphering hex is a bit beyond my pay grade. If you want a quality answer head over to the C part of stackoverflow, those guys will help you out.